# Formsflow.ai conditional text field

Tags: formsflow.ai

I have a From in Formsflow.ai, and I need to make a text field hidden till a certain text box is checked, then the text field should appear. I tried to do it with simple logic but it is not working out so far, I made the field hidden and added a trigger (check box has the value true) that would trigger an action, which is change the hidden property to False how can I do it (prefer simple logic)
how can i do it (prefer simple logic)

Comment: Can you share any code snippet or Sample screenshot you tried? You can hide a field with conditional tab and adding simple vs advanced Conditions in there on the form component setting in designer.  Have a check here : https://help.form.io/userguide/form-building/logic-and-conditions#conditional-show-and-hide